# Discriminate Doctrine Relationship

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to discriminate the rows that get populated in a relationship in Doctrine?

For example: I have a one-to-many relationship where the target entity has a `deleted` column. I'd like any row with this column set to `true` to not end up in the collection.

I can't find anything like this in the documentation, so there's a chance that this isn't even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot discriminate rows during hydration.

What you can do is either using an [SQL filter](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html) that will filter ANY data coming from the database or filter the collection in your getters with the [criteria API](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) ([example here](https://gist.github.com/3368674)), which is available since [Doctrine 2.3](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine-2-3-final.html):

```php
public function getUsers()
{
    $criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();

    $criteria->andWhere($criteria->expr()->eq('deleted', false));

    return $this->users->matching($criteria);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm already filtering in the getter; I was just hoping to save myself an iteration over the collection. Thanks!

Comment: @Blake the criteria API applies such filtering at SQL level where possible, so don't be worried about iterations.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm stuck with Doctrine 2.1 for various reasons, so the filtering API isn't available to me.

Comment: @Blake too bad :( That means iterating or using `Collection#filter`

Answer (score 0):

There is also a "softdelete" extension which uses filter. This is in my opinion a cleaner solution and you dont have to repeat the task in every getter. You can activate the filter by default and in the rare cases where you need deleted records you can deactivate the filter. I think it would be more performant as well:
https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions